# Creating an admin-authorized blog using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've been creating blogs using various RoR tutorials I've found around the internet (right now I'm working on the one found on Udemy, though I'm sure they're all similar), and currently I'm working on a blog with RailsAdmin where users can submit posts and the admin has the ability to review and delete them.

However, I'm trying to set it up so that posts can be submitted, but cannot be viewed on the page until the admin approves them, and I've been through several app creations but I can't figure out how this works. I apologize if this is a total newbie question but it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest only displaying the posts that have a "published" field (make this a boolean called :published. on the admin side, have it run so that only the admin can see that field and if they check the check box, the post is then "published" and viewable by everyone.

in terminal

```
rails g migration add_published_to_posts
```

in your migration file

```
class AddPublishedToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :published, :boolean
  end
end
```

in terminal

```
rake db:migrate
```

then in your posts index method (in the posts controller)

```
@posts = Post.where(:published => true)
```

I'm not going to write out the form for you, but you get the idea...

I would also investigate [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise%20%22Devise) as gem for setting up authorization for the admin.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! I also already have Devise set up for RailsAdmin, this is the only thing I was having serious trouble with. 

I also had some issues with solr but I'm pretty sure that's just because I installed it to the wrong directory.